# DB Instance Shutdown while in Inconsistent State

Tags: database, oracle

I want to know if a database is in inconsistent state and if we manually shutdown the db ,will the dirty buffers be written   to the data blocks first  or is it taken care when we restart the instance using the redo logs files?

Comment: Define inconsistent.

Comment: @Balazs Papp Inconsistent here means that there are some bad buffers that the commited data has not yet been written by the DBWR(background process) to the datafiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you shut down the database.

`shutdown normal|transactional|immediate` performs a checkpoint before shutdown, leaving the datafiles in an up-to-date consistent state, so you will be able to open the database again without the redo logs.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT89045

> When Oracle Database Initiates Checkpoints
>
> ...
>
> Consistent database shutdown

`shutdown abort` does an unclean shutdown, and the database will perform a crash recovery from the redo logs the next time it is opened.

Comment: Just wanted one more answer regarding this , if I had used shutdown abort and while crash recovery the db is not able to find a redo log file which is accidently deleted. Will the database instance ever start?

Comment: In that case you have lost data, and the database should be restored from backup. You can still try to open the database in an irregular way with a specific hidden parameter, but there is no guarantee it will work, the database may just crash after a few seconds or not even open.

Comment: Irregular way using the hidden parameter, Can you please tell about that ? The problem I am facing is that the database is not starting as soon as I startup the database ,the connection terminates.Can you also tell if it is possible for me to create a  new instance and add the datafiles of the old instance to it.Thanks for your reply